# echo category name as a link

Tags: php, variables

I have the following code and instead of the 'read more' link I want it to display the name of the category as the link. Does anybody have any idea how I can achieve this?

```
    $the_cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category_name = $the_cat[0]->cat_name;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $the_cat[0]->cat_ID );
    $slider_gallery.= '<br/><span class="chpcs_more"><a href="'.$category_link.'">read more</a></span>';
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using wordpress, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$slider_gallery.= '<br/><span class="chpcs_more"><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category_name.'</a></span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same as you did with the category link like so:

```
$the_cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category_name = $the_cat[0]->cat_name;
$category_link = get_category_link( $the_cat[0]->cat_ID );
$slider_gallery.= '<br/><span class="chpcs_more"><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category_name.'</a></span>';
```